# How to save Scrapy items from pipeline in MySQL table by order from another table (multiple tables)?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, scrapy, web-crawler

This is my first question in Stackoverflow ever. :P Everything work just fine, except a crawl order, I add a priority method but didn`t work correctly. Need to first write all author data, then all album and songs data and store to DB with this order. I want to query items in a MySql table by order from item in another one.

Database structure: https://i.postimg.cc/GhF4w32x/db.jpg

Example: first write all author items in Author table, and then order album items in Album table by authorId from Author table.

Github repository: https://github.com/markostalma/discogs/tree/master/discogs

P.S. I have a three item class for author, album and song parser.

Also I was tried to make a another flow of spider and put all in one item class, but with no success. Order was a same. :(

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup an item pipeline for this. I would suggest using SQL Alchemy to build the SQL item and connect to the DB. You're SQL Alchemy class will reflect all the table relationships you have in your DB schema. Let me show you. This is a working example of a similar pipeline that I have except you would setup your class on the SQLAlchemy to container the m2m or foreignkey relationships you need. You'll have to refer to their [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html) [1] .

An even more pythonic way of doing this would be to keep your SQL Alchemy class and item names the same and do something like for k,v in item.items():
This way you can just loop the item and set what is there. Code is long and violates DRY for a purpose though.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey, Boolean, Sequence, Date, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
import datetime


DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

def db_connect():
    """
    This function connections to the database. Tables will automatically be created if they do not exist.
    See __tablename__ under RateMds class
    MySQL example: engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')
    """
    return create_engine('sqlite:///reviews.sqlite', echo=True)


class GoogleReviewItem(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'google_review_item'
    pk = Column('pk', String, primary_key=True)
    query = Column('query', String(500))
    entity_name = Column('entity_name', String(500))
    user = Column('user', String(500))
    review_score = Column('review_score', Integer)
    description = Column('description', String(5000))
    top_words = Column('top_words', String(10000), nullable=True)
    bigrams = Column('bigrams', String(10000), nullable=True)
    trigrams = Column('trigrams', String(10000), nullable=True)
    google_average = Column('google_average', Integer)
    total_reviews = Column('total_reviews', Integer)
    review_date = Column('review_date', DateTime)
    created_on = Column('created_on', DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)


engine = db_connect()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def create_individual_table(engine):
    # checks for tables existance and creates them if they do not already exist
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

create_individual_table(engine)
session = Session()

def get_row_by_pk(pk, model):
    review = session.query(model).get(pk)
    return review

class GooglePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        review = get_row_by_pk(item['pk'], GoogleReviewItem)
        if review is None:
            googlesite = GoogleReviewItem(
                query=item['query'],
                google_title=item['google_title'],
                review_score=item['review_score'],
                review_count=item['review_count'],
                website=item['website'],
                website_type=item['website_type'],
                top_words=item['top_words'],
                bigrams=item['bigrams'],
                trigrams=item['trigrams'],
                text=item['text'],
                date=item['date']
            )
            session.add(googlesite)
            session.commit()
            return item
        else:
            raise DropItem()


  [1]: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html
```

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately I need to use MySQL or PostgreSQL database because it is a one of conditions for exam. I will try to change my pipeline to finish crawling on right way. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem it looks like you got it to work for your DB. The same applies except for the DB connection as long as your MySQL or Postgres db is setup right the rest will be the same. SQLAlchemy handles most of the differences I believe except certain features are different depending on the DB in question.